# Using the Korg Krome Keyboard Workstation

Tags: software

I got the Korg Krome Keyboard Workstation a while back and I am still having trouble using it. Are there any good resources that you know out there to help me learn it. Or perhaps someone could give me some insight on the different functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all likelihood the best resource for getting started with it is [Korg's own Krome quickstart guide](http://www.korg.com/uploads/Support/USA_KROME_QS_E.pdf). The [Krome Workstation web page](http://www.korg.com/Krome) has, under the "Support and Downloads" link in the lower-left, a few more bits of documentation about how it all works.

As with most manuals you'll probably have to refer back to it now and again as you become more familiar with more features, rather than trying to memorize everything in one go.

Comment: I don't know if you have ever read the Korg manual yourself, but it is probably one of the most confusing manuals I've ever read. It's like they expect you to already understand so many large and confusing concepts. Along with that I have not found a place in the manual where it gives specifics on things such as exporting songs, uploading sounds, and such. I appreciate the answer and I hope other users will find the manual more helpful than I have.

Comment: @MattCamp I haven't read this particular manual deeply, but I've read a few other Korg manuals and glancing through it it looks pretty similar - a bit obtuse, but the info is there. Exporting, for example, is done by writing them to an SD card and appears to be only in proprietary or .MID format. It's covered under "Saving and Loading" in the quickstart guide on p.19.

Comment: I will try and give it a more in-depth look. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MattCamp Sure thing! Best of luck in getting it all figured out. If, in reading, you come up with conceptual questions that aren't covered (e.g. "Why doesn't a .MID include my specific instrument sounds?) Feel free to post them. Specific and answerable are the main criteria for a great question.

Comment: I think most Korg manuals are very good readable, but I have a quite good understanding of the underlying terms. However, what's wrong with reading it and for any unclearity ask a question in this forum (helps others too)?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers There's nothing wrong with that at all. In fact, that's exactly how this site is supposed to work. We do ask though that the questions are appropriately scoped - "how does X work?" is good, "can anyone give me some general pointers on X?" is usually too vague to be useful on a Q&A site (although that seems to work on some forums)

Answer (score 0):

I think the synth comes with some manuals (some printed, some on PDF); I don't have a Krome, but several other Korg synths (and all are more or less equal).

- Read the start guide
- Read the operation guide
- Do not read the parameter guide from beginning to end

Some tips:

- First play the programs, get a feeling how programs are organized
- Than try combinations, try to change them (combi editing is easier than program editing)
- Check the global section
- Together this is called PCG (Programs, Combis, Global)